# calculating minimum distance between a point and the coast

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I am trying to get the minimum distance between a given point and the coast. My example is the distance of Madrid to the coast:

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
coast <- readShapeLines("Natural_Earth_quick_start/10m_physical/ne_10m_coastline.shp")
MAD = readWKT("POINT(-3.716667 40.383333)")
gDistance(MAD,coast)
[1] 3.021808
```

I am having trouble understanding what `gDistance()` returns. The docs say it's in the units of the projection. Does that mean it is in latlong degrees? How can I convert that to kilometers?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your map? As a start, type `proj4string(coast)` to see what the projection is. If there is a `+units=' string, then those are the units.

Comment: The map I'm using is the coastline from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/. `proj4string(coast)` returns `NA`

Comment: Have you looked at the definition of Hausdorff distance linked from the help page?. I get the idea that this answer is in "degrees" but I'm not at all convinced that is meaningful since the number of km in a "degree" varies from  roughly 100 at the equator to zero at the poles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`gDistance(...)` returns the minimum Cartesian (Euclidean) distance between the point and feature set provided as arguments. Since your map is in long/lat coordinates, you get distance in "degrees", e.g.

> d = sqrt { (long<sub>1</sub> - long<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (lat<sub>1</sub> - lat<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> }

where long and lat are in decimal degrees. As was pointed out, this doesn't mean much because converting to planar distance (say, km) depends on where you are. So we need to transform your data into a CRS which is approximately planar in the region of interest. It turns out that the appropriate CRS for Spain is [EPSG-2062](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2062/). The projection string for EPSG-2062 is:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.9988085293 +x_0=600000 +y_0=600000 +a=6378298.3 +b=6356657.142669561 +pm=madrid +units=m +no_defs
```

which has `+units=m` (meters). So we need to reproject both the point (MAD) and the borders to EPSG-2062.

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)

epsg.2062 <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.9988085293 +x_0=600000 +y_0=600000 +a=6378298.3 +b=6356657.142669561 +pm=madrid +units=m +no_defs"
wgs.84    <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

coast <- readShapeLines("ne_10m_coastline",CRS(wgs.84))
MAD   <- readWKT("POINT(-3.716667 40.383333)",p4s=CRS(wgs.84))
gDistance(MAD,coast)            # WGS-84 (long/lat) projection, units in "degrees"
# [1] 3.021808

coast.proj <- spTransform(coast,CRS(epsg.2062))
MAD.proj   <- spTransform(MAD,CRS(epsg.2062))
gDistance(MAD.proj,coast.proj)  #EPSG-2062 projection, units are in meters.
# [1] 305171.2
```

So the minimum distance is ~305.2km.

Finally, note that your coastline file has all the coastlines of the world, so this is the minimum distance to *some* coastline, not necessarily the Spanish coast (although in this case it does turn out to be on the northern coast of Spain). If your reference point was very near the border with Portugal, the the nearest coastal point would be to the western coast of Portugal.

Comment: Thanks!, that is exactly what I wanted. How do you know that it's the northern coast?

Comment: The short answer is that I looked at a map, but looking again, Madrid might be closer to the Mediterranean coast near Castellon. There is a way to identify the coordinates of the closest point but it's complicated. If you need to know that you should post as a separate question.

Comment: This looks great but what projection should I use when calculating the distance of points (in km) to nearest shore at a global scale? I have ~250 points!

Comment: This answer doesn't generalize well.