# Calculating distance to nearest shore from multiple GPS coordinates

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, polygon, distance

I have tried using the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295302/calculating-minimum-distance-between-a-point-and-the-coast) to solve this problem but I cannot apply it in my case since I have many coordinates distributed at a global scale.

Does anyone have a way to calculate the minimum distance in km from a series of points to the nearest shore using a loop? This is a subset of the points I am using [(DATA HERE)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1m7pcgn7kslgdw/Sites.csv?dl=0)

```
#setwd and load directories----
setwd("your_wd")
  require (ggplot2)
  require (ggmap)

#build a map to plot distribution of sample sites ----
sites<-read.csv("sites.csv", header=T)

#Using GGPLOT, plot the Base World Map
mp <- NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray50", fill="gray50") # create a layer of borders
mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld
#Now Layer the sites on top
Lon<-sites$x
Lat<-sites$y
mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=Lon, y=Lat),color="blue", size=3) 
mp
```

[image: Distribution of sites]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `rgeos` package

```
library(rgeos)
gDistance(spPoints, spPolygon, byid = TRUE)
```

`spPoints` will be a `SpatialPoints` object holding the coordinates. `spPolygon` will be a `SpatialPolygons` objects with landmasses. See the `sp` package. Make sure that both object have the same projection and have a sensible projection.

Comment: Yup, I tried this but its selecting a projection that is the problem. the default is WGS84 for both the points and the polygon but the distances Im getting are very odd.